# How do I query GraphQL schema when the argument is an input type?

Tags: graphql

I am getting a bit confused with how to query the following GraphQL schema. I am trying to query *pokemons* to pull search results, but the fact that PokemonQueryInput! is called in the argument and PokemonConnection! is the result is confusing me. **How do I properly add filter as an argument? And how do I properly utilize PokemonConnection?**

---

*schema.graphql*

```
    type Query {
        pokemons(query: PokemonsQueryInput!): PokemonConnection!
        pokemonByName(name: String!): Pokemon
        pokemonById(id: ID!): Pokemon
        pokemonTypes: [String!]!
    }

    input PokemonsQueryInput {
        limit: Int = 10
        offset: Int = 0
        search: String
        filter: PokemonFilterInput
    }

    input PokemonFilterInput {
        type: String
        isFavorite: Boolean
    }

    type PokemonConnection {
        limit: Int!
        offset: Int!
        count: Int!
        edges: [Pokemon!]!
    }

    type Pokemon {
        id: ID!
        number: Int!
        name: String!
        ...
    }
```

*index.js*

```
pokemons: (__, args) => {
      const { limit, offset, search, filter } = args.query;
      let pokemons = pokemonsData;

      if (search) {
        const regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
        pokemons = _.filter(pokemons, p => p.name.match(regex));
      }

      if (filter) {
        if (filter.type) {
          const regex = new RegExp(filter.type, 'i');
          pokemons = _.filter(pokemons,p => _.some(p.types, t => t.match(regex)));
        }

        if (filter.isFavorite) {
          pokemons = _.filter(pokemons, p => !!favorites.get(p.id));
        }
      }

      const count = pokemons.length;
      const edges = pokemons.slice(offset, offset + limit);

      return {
        limit,
        offset,
        count,
        edges
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located the solution for how to do this via the GraphQL documentation on Object types: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/object-types/. Types can be declared as arguments by nesting them within { }.

```
{
  pokemons(query: {filter: {type: "Water"}}) {
    edges {
      name
    }
  }
}
```